# JavaScript function detects cookie set during session, but not a pre-existing cookie at start of new session

Tags: javascript, cookies

The function call `cookieExists('stylesheet')` should detect the presence of a cookie, returning true if the cookie called 'stylesheet' is present and false if not.

```
function cookieExists(name) {
   var ckArr = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(i = 0; i < ckArr.length; i++)
   if (ckArr[i].split('=')[0].trim() == name) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

This function is designed to check through the names of all existing cookies, but I am using it on a page which will only ever have one cookie - and its name is 'stylesheet'. I am calling it on pageload to check if the cookie called 'stylesheet' exists. This cookie specifies the CSS file last used (users can choose either stylesheet): either stylesheet1.css or stylesheet2.css. If the cookie called 'stylesheet' exists, I want to use the stylesheet specified in the cookie to display the page.

Now, if there actually is no existing cookie called 'stylesheet', `cookieExists('stylesheet')` does return false. If I then add a cookie called 'stylesheet' to the page, `cookieExists('stylesheet')` returns true. So far, so good.

However, if I then close the browser tab - while there is the cookie called 'stylesheet' attached to the page - and then open the same page in a new tab, `cookieExists('stylesheet')` no longer detects the cookie and returns false! The cookie is still attached to the page - it has not expired at the end of the previous session.

To be clear, I'm calling `cookieExists('stylesheet')` on pageload with `window.onload = findStylesheet;`, where the function `findStylesheet()` calls `cookieExists('stylesheet')`:

```
function findStylesheet() {
  let savedStylesheet = cookieExists('stylesheet');
  if (savedStylesheet) {
    let setStylesheet = Cookies.get('stylesheet');
    let newStylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet");
    newStylesheet.setAttribute('href', setStylesheet);
   }
}
```

The function `Cookies.get('stylesheet')` is a `js-cookie` function.

I would be very grateful if someone could point out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED - I had been working offline. When I put the pages concerned online, everything worked. So I learned something there.

What is interesting to me is that the cookies 'worked' offline with Firefox. I could set, update and read cookies. I just couldn't read a cookie that existed from a previous session at the start of a new session. However, with Chrome, nothing worked.

Thanks to Alias C for his ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding an expiration attribute to your `Cookies.set()`? After testing with your code I believe that may be one issue, the other is that your cookieExists function did not work for a cookie that was found by my other code, so that may be another issue. I changed the findStylesheet function to this:

```
function findStylesheet() {
  let savedStylesheet = Cookies.get('stylesheet');
  if (savedStylesheet) {
    let newStylesheet = document.getElementById("stylesheet");
    newStylesheet.setAttribute('href', setStylesheet);
    return true;
   }
  return false;
}
```

Also I used a test method to check the cookie: `Cookies.set('stylesheet', 'path-to-stylesheet',{ expires: 365 });`(Note the **expires** in the brackets). This code worked for me and when I closed and opened the browser the cookie was still there, however, the cookie is not found if I leave out the expires.

Comment: Thnks for your answer. Yes, my cookie has an expiration date - it is not expired. Verified in browser console. I agree the function `cookieExists` is no good. I have also tried the function `getCookie` [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) and get the same results! Your function `Cookies.set` seems to be missing its value. However, I did not specify the path in _my_  `Cookies.set` . I have started using the functions from w3schools (they include path - see link above), but I get the same result. These results were with Firefox; just tried with Chrome - can't even set a cookie!

Comment: Another possibility is the environment. When I tried to set the cookie in an unhosted page(and even jsfiddle) it wasn't working at all. You may have to set up a different host environment to check if it's working or try to use [localstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) instead.